# zero-Day Security Vulnerabilities in Java 7 Update 10

Tags: java, security

I was reading the Tech-articles about the *zero-Day Security Vulnerabilities in Java 7 Update 10* on 11th Jan and on 13th Jan, Came to know that Oracle has released a fix Patches *Update 11* for the same Vulnerabilities. But All the news was just containing superficial data.

Can anyone explain what the Vulnerabilities were and what was the fix?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a technical report for the recent Java zero-day exploit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14306798/is-there-a-technical-report-for-the-recent-java-zero-day-exploit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, There was a bug where an applet with a "Medium" level security model in Java 7's MethodHandle native code which allowed you to unset the SecurityManager even if you had one already.  This effectively gave you access of a local program.  It would have the same access as the process

This didn't happen if your security level was "High" which is recommended and the default.

i.e. You had to lower your security level first, but the bug lowered it lower than it should have. ;)

Comment: Short and Crisp. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I believe Medium was the default in Java 7 Update 10, they moved it up to High with Update 11.

Comment: I have Java 8 ea which is set to `High (recommended)` ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can read about it ... the release notes

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u11-relnotes-1896856.html

The bug description can be found at 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/security/alert-cve-2013-0422-1896849.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for providing the details.

Answer (score 1):

An analysis can be found here:

https://partners.immunityinc.com/idocs/Java%20MBeanInstantiator.findClass%200day%20Analysis.pdf

It boils down to `sun.reflect.Reflection.getCallerClass(int)` not correctly handling the newly introduced Reflection API.